# sql server grant, revoke permission to a user

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, winforms

I wrote a simple c# code that connect to sql-server database and execute a query:

```
        cmd = new SqlCommand(txtQuery.Text.ToString().Trim(), con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

- in my db I have a table named myTB. I have two users too: user1(owner), user2(new user created)
- I **logged in** (connected to DB) with **user2**'s username and password !
- I can access the tables that created by user1 with the query bellow:

  **"select * from user1.myTB"**

  (I don't know why I get error with this query:"select * from myTB", forget it now!)
- Now I wanna **REVOKE** 'select' permission from user2. I mean I don't want user2 to execute the **select query** on myTB table which is created by user1.
- what should I do is a problem that I'm stuck on it !
  I used this query, but nothing changed !

Q1: "Revoke select ON user1.myTB FROM user2"

again user2 can do select * from user1.myTB !!! WHY !?

please help me with this.
thanks.

Comment: If you execute `select * from myTB` you are effectively telling SQL Server that myTB exists in the default schema (dbo unless it's been changed). In this case, although you don't explicitly state it, myTB is clearly owned by user1's schema which is why `select * from user1.myTB` works, because you have correctly specified where the table is. Generally speaking it is accepted good practice to always specify the schema in which a table resides unless you are super lazy and have left everything in dbo, which is frowned upon in many cases.

Comment: Incidentally I occasionally include myself in the super-lazy category - that particular sentence was meant in general not specifically aimed at you or your work!! :)

Comment: @StevePettifer It's OK ;) But my problem is on ! I don't know how to revoke select permission from a user ! :( no one answered me here !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

user2 is probably getting it's permissions from a role membership.

Run:

```
use [<YourDatabase>]
GO

exec sp_helpuser
```

find the user in the first column, and then look at the second column. Is the user a member of `db_datareader` or `db_owner`?

If so, you can revoke membership, say for db_datareader, by doing:

```
exec sp_droprolemember 'db_datareader', 'user2'
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot REVOKE something you did not GRANT. Looks like you want to:

1. investigate and understand *why* `user2` has permission to SELECT
2. possibly DENY permission to SELECT to `user2`

The permission work like following:

- initialy an user has the poermissions derived from his group mebership (including public roles)
- GRANT explictly grants a privilege
- REVOKE takes back a *previously granted* priviledge, reverting to the user having the privileges implictily inherited from group(s) memberhip
- DENY denies a privilege

The rules of precedence are that any DENY take precedence over any GRANT or inherited privilege. One can get access through a number of GRANTs but one single DENY will revoke the privilege. You cannot GRANT/REVOKE/DENY permissions to the securable owner (members of `db_owner` own *everything* and members of `sysadmin` own *everything* on the entire server).

Comment: Thansk. You'r right. but what should I do now? How could I REVOKE select permission from a table ( even if the table is in dbo )

Answer (score 0):

Thanks friends,
I've solved it and use DENY instead of REVOKE :

**DENY** select ON user1.myTB TO user2

Comment: To be fair, Remus Rusanu did suggest the use of `DENY` in the first instance so his answer should be the accepted one.